# Finding the upper boundary of a sequence to find it's limit

Tags: real-analysis

I have to determine if the following sequences converge and if they converge I have to determine to what they converge and proof this.

$$ a_n = 2^{-n}  \\ b_n = \frac{n^2}{n^3 -10} \\ c_n = 1 +(-1)^n \\ d_n = 2^{1/n}$$

It's obvious to me that only $c_n$ doesn't converge. The limits I found are:
$$a_n = 0, \  b_n=0, \ d_n = 1 $$

I think I have proven the limit for $a_n$ by taking $N= ceil(1/\epsilon)$, thus if n>N $$|2^{-n}| < |\frac{1}{n}|< \epsilon $$
Do I need to show that $2^{-n}<1/n$, because this is quite obvious to me.
For $b_n$ I tried to do the same thing, but I'm stuck at finding a useful upper boundary for this expression. The same problem I have with $d_n$, I tried to use $\frac{n+1}{n}$ but I can't show that this is larger or equal to $2^{1/n}$ for all n. Could someone please help me finding good expressions to proof that these sequences converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b)$: $0<b_n = \dfrac{n^2}{n^3-10} < \dfrac{1}{n-10}$ , $n > 10$. Apply squeeze theorem to get the limit of $0$.

$c):$ Use a trick inequality: $1<d_n=2^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 1\cdots 1\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}< \dfrac{(n-2)\cdot 1 + 2\sqrt{2}}{n}= 1 + \dfrac{2\sqrt{2}-2}{n}$, and apply squeeze theorem here to get the limit of $1$.

Comment: b is quite obvious now, you can just pick N to be 10 or larger right? cause then the inequality holds. But for c I don't see how you find this inequality, it's not very obvious to me

Comment: Right. And for $c)$, its called "AM-GM" inequality.